# How can I make my array into a formatted string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to format my array to a formatted string, how can I do that?
The instructions I was given are

Task 6 - find all odd numbers in a list.

Allow any number of Number arguments to be passed to the function.
 If a value is passed to the function that is not a Number, ignore it
 and continue processing the rest. If the list is empty (nothing passed
 to the function, or all need to be ignored, return `null`).

Return a formatted string with all odd numbers in a list, for example:

"1, 3, 5"

```
<script>
var odd = [];

const oddNumbers = (...numbers) => {
  var oddNum
  var formatString;
  var i;

  if (numbers.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      if (isNaN(numbers[i]) === false && (numbers[i] % 2 !== 0)) {
        odd.push(numbers[i]);
        console.log(odd);
      }
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
  return odd;
};

oddNumbers(1, 2, 34, 54, 55, 34, 32, 11, 19, 17, 54, 66, 13);

alert(odd);
</script>
```

Comment: `numbers.filter(n => n % 2 !== 0).join(", ")`

Comment: @epascarello That'll include non-numbers as well, and doesn't check for length 0

Comment: I'd use `const odds = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        const num = numbers[i];
        if (typeof num === 'number' && num % 2 === 1) {
          odds.push(num);
        }
      }
      if (odds.length === 0) {
        return null;
      }
      return odds.join(', ');`

Comment: not that hard to add non number check `!isNaN(n)` and is not really a full answer, hence a comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just `join` your array into string:

```
else{
     return null;
}
return odd.join(', ');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const oddNumbers = (...numbers) => {
  var odd = [];
  var oddNum
  var formatString;
  var i;

  if (Array.isArray(numbers)) {
    for (i in numbers) {
      if (isNaN(numbers[i]) === false && (numbers[i] % 2 !== 0)) {
        odd.push(numbers[i]);
      }
    }
  } else {
    return [];
  }
  return odd;
};

var result = oddNumbers(1, 2, 34, 54, 55, 34, 32, 11, 19, 17, 54, 66, 13);

console.log(result.join(', '))
```